# How do I perform php artisan migration in AWS production environment with container_commands?

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I deployed my Laravel application to ELB

I run commands after deployment with container_commands in .ebextension config files.

But when in production environment I get

```
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

Command Cancelled!
```

How can I enable this automatically?

Comment: commands like php artisan migrate ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about laravel commands then you can define a route and call the commands. Check example code below:

```
Route::get('/run_migrations', function () {
try {
    dump('Init with app tables migrations...');
    dump(Artisan::call( 'migrate', ['--step'=> ''] ));
    dump('Done with app tables migrations');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    Response::make($e->getMessage(), 500);
}
});
```

Comment: I think in this case anyone can run migrations so it's not secure?

Comment: @hanachan That would not make a difference. I mean this route will be specifically for run migrations and what will migrations do it's totally up to you. So, anyone can go to this route yes of course, but they can't do except to just visit the url. Getting my point ?

Comment: and I am not sure what are you asking about how to call curl from AWS... if you can explain it a little bit more that would be helpfull....